# Neighborhoods necessary for convergence of a sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is a follow-on to a question I posed yesterday. It pertains to
Edwards's Advance Calculus of Several Variables, Chapter III.

Given a real-valued function $f(x)$, continuously differentiable
and monotonic on the interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that
it changes sign between $a$ and $b$, the sequence${\{x_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}}$
defined by $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime}(x_{n})}$ and
$x_{0}\in[a,b]$ converges to a root of $f$. Edwards doesn't offer
a proof, and the fact is only used as a motivating example.

Using a diagram, he demonstrates that the modified sequence $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}$
may fail to converge.

I concocted the example that $f(x)=\sin x$ will fail to converge
if $x_{0}=\frac{\tan x_{0}}{2}$ because $x_{1}=x_{0}-\frac{\sin x_{0}}{\cos x_{0}}=-x_{0}$
so $x_{2}=-x_{0}+\frac{\sin x_{0}}{\cos x_{0}}=x_{0}$.

Edwards uses the contraction mapping theorem to prove that for $f^{\prime}>0$
and $M=\max f^{\prime}([a,b])$, the modification $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{M}$
will produce a convergant sequence under the above stated conditions.

He then uses the contraction mapping theorem to show that it is possible
to solve $f[x]=y$ for $x$ when $y$ is given ``near'' some $f[x_{0}]=y_{0}$
with known values for $x_{0}$, $f^{\prime}(x_{0})$ and $y_{0}$.
In this case he uses $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})-y}{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}$
as the generic term in the sequence. But I observe that $g(x)=f(x)-y$
leads to $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{g(x_{n})}{g^{\prime}(x_{0})}$. The
sequence of these terms will converge to the same value of $x$, where
$f(x)=y$ and $g(x)=0$. So $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})-y}{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}$
is suseptible to the same vulnerability as is $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}$.

> Theorem 1.3 Let $f:\mathbb{R\rightarrow\mathbb{R}}$ be a $\mathscr{C^{1}}$
>   function such that $f(a)=b$ and $f^{\prime}(a)\ne0$. Then there
>   exist neighborhoods $\mathit{U}=[a-\delta,a+\delta]$ of $a$ and
>   $\mathit{V}=[b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]$ of $b$ such that, given $y_{*}\in\mathit{V}$,
>   the sequence ${\{x_{n}\}_{0}^{\infty}}$ defined inductively
>   by 
>   $$x_{0}=a, x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})-y}{f^{\prime}(a)}$$
>    converges to a (unique) point $x_{*}\in\mathit{U}$ such that $f(x_{*})=y_{*}$.
>
> PROOF Chose $\delta>0$ so small that $|f^{\prime}(a)-f^{\prime}(x)|\le\frac{1}{2}|f^{\prime}(a)|$
>   if $\mathit{x\in U}=[a-\delta,a+\delta]$. Then let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\delta|f^{\prime}(a)|$. ...

The proof uses the contraction mapping theorem with these stated assumptions.

My question is: how does restricting the domain and range in this
way eliminate the previously demonstrated pitfall?  Put another way: what are the least restrictive neighborhoods necessary for convergence?

The generic problematic condition appears to be $-f(x)=f(-x)$ with
 $2x_{n}f'(x_{n})=f(x_{n})$.

Comment: I think I have answer.  The slope at the origin is greater than the slope of the cord between the origin and the problem point.  The slope of the cord is twice the derivative at the problem point.  Restricting the abscissa so that derivative varies by less than 1/2 of its value ensures the x value of evaluation is closer to the origin than is the problematic value.  I am posting by phone, so this is very terse.  Hope to flesh it out soon.

Comment: The  quote from the book is incorrect without  extra condtions on $f$......(1).  $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ may be strictly monotonic and still have a point $c\in [a,b]$ where $f'(c)=0\ne f(c).$  E.g., $f(x)=x^3-1$ and $[a,b]=[-1,2]$ and $c=0.$ If $x_n=c$ for some $n$ then $x_{n+1}$ is undefined,....(2).  Even if $f'$ does not vanish on $[a,b]$ there can exist $d\in [a,b]$ with $|f(d)/f'(d)|>(b-a).$  If $x_n=d$ for some $n$ then $x_{n+1}\not \in [a,b].$ E.g. if $f(a)=-1$ and $f'(a)=2(b-a),$ if $x_0$ is equal to $a$ , or sufficiently close to $a$, then $x_1>b.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet If you are referring to the statement not shown as a block quote, that is my fault.  I used the term monotonic, incorrectly.  The stipulation is that $f^{\prime}(x)\ne0$.  That's part of why I post here.  I am largely autodidactic.  Discussing mathematics with people who know what they are talking about helps me stay (or become) honest.  Thank you.

Comment: As my second example shows, even $f'\ne 0$ on $[a,b]$, with $f'$ continuous, is insufficient, as we may get $x_1>b,$ and  even if $f$ is defined on $(b,\infty)$ its behavior on  $(b,\infty)$ can be almost anything.... I dk whether your text provides a reference. This method of approximating a solution to $f(x)=0$ is called Newton's Method, or the Newton-Raphson Method. In practice it is very useful and widely applied.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You are correct. I added a second graphic depicting the example I came up with.  It's a circle centered on the $x$ axis below the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises when the mapping is symmetric about the origin.
Taking the case where $f^{\prime}[x]>0$, the ``loop'' condition
occurs when $2xf^{\prime}[x]=f[x]$. This is because

$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f[x_{n}]}{f^{\prime}[x_{n}]}$, $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-2x_{n}=-x_{n}$.
By the symmetry of the function, that leads to $x_{n+2}=x_{n}$, etc.
Let $x_{p}$ be that value of $x$ where the loop occurs.

Note that the chord drawn from the origin to $\{x_{p},f[x_{p}]\}$
has a slope $f[x_{p}]/x_{p}=2f^{\prime}[x_{p}]<f^{\prime}[0]$. So
$\frac{1}{2}f^{\prime}[0]>f^{\prime}[x_{p}]$. By inspection it is
apparent that the graph is concave-down to the right of the origin.
So for $0<x_{n}<x_{p}$, $f^{\prime}[x_{n}]>f^{\prime}[x_{p}]$ and
$x_{n+1}$will safely land somewhere between $-x_{p}$ and the origin.
From this, it can be seen that restricting $|x|<\delta\implies|f^{\prime}[x]-f^{\prime}[0]|\le\frac{1}{2}|f^{\prime}[0]|$
avoids the loop condition.

I know this is not a rigorous argument.  I will post a follow-on question, time permitting.
[image: Here is a graphic depiction of the situation.]

An example showing that a sequence with $x_{0}\in[a,b]$ might not converge. [image: will not converge.]